# CoreData+MagicalRecord How to unit test if a record is successfully persisted into sqlite file

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord 2.2. I am writing test case to see if a record has been successfully persisted to sqlite. What I am doing is:

1. `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore]` to create a in-memory sqlite database
2. `Entity* entity = [Entity MR_createEntity]` to create an entity
3. Persist the entity to sqlite (this will not affect the 4th step)
4. Now I want to fetch the entity like: `Entity* fetchedEntity = [Entity MR_findAll][0]`

But this way the entity can be fetched without persisting to sqlite, since it can be directly accessed from the context. **Is there a way to create a new context from the database or how can I force the coredata to read from database** so I can know if it has been successfully persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Entity MR_createEntity]` is short form for

```
[Entity MR_createEntityInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_<some context>]]
```

Create your own two contexts based on `MR_defaultContext` using:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *saveContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSManagedObjectContext *testContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

The command in 2. will become:

```
Entity *entity = [Entity MR_createEntityInContext:saveContext]
```

line 4. will become

```
Entity *fetchedEntity = [Entity MR_findAllInContext:textContext][0]
```

Strictly speaking by using two context you are not testing if the entity has been persisted, but the communication between two contexts. To my knowledge there is no method to tell if the entity is fetched from storage or from an internal core data cache. For more confidence, before fetching in `testContext` reset `saveContext` and verify that `saveContext` has forgotten about the entity.

Typically persisting will fail if your entity does not match the validation limits, those set in the data model or in your validation methods. Once the entity passes validation it tends to get saved, too.

IMHO writing a unit test for the verification between validation and saving to the store is too much work. Just trust the API unless having really truly reasonable doubt.

Comment: I think I'd better just trust the API.